# Storing external api credentials in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making a project in MVC which acts as a dashboard.

Currently I have login credentials stored as variables within a config file in my project. I have it set so that There are a number of methods which in turn Authenticate the User against a website's API and then make a GET to retrieve a JSON string specific to that user.

I would like to have it so that different users can log in to the program with their credentials for this API and then retrieve their unique JSON string.

From what I've seen, anything on MVC to do with logins uses a DB, but as I am authenticating against an external site, I was wondering if there was a way I could do this locally, storing the users credentials as variables such as:

```
     public class Config
{
    public static string email;
    public static string password;
}
```

Comment: Do you have certain login mechanism for your dashboard to identify the user? If yes, then what is it? how id the identity being managed?

Comment: The user is being logged in to use an external websites API rather than logging in to the dashboard. I would like to allow different users to use the API  by logging in with their own credentials, just using a "login" as a mean to pass their credentials through to my API POST

Comment: I recommend that you should definitely use databsae. Create or update user record in db when user logs in. Else you could use the Identity object and set up userdata claim for storing password. But storing passwords in application memory is NOT at all recommended. Even when you store password in db you should store a hash.

Comment: I don't want to store a permanent record of the user. The purpose of this is just to pass credentials through to make a call to an API and then when the application is closed or the user logs out, there is no memory of this login